# Query that loop between columns and select the column name

Tags: sql-server, while-loop, sql-server-2012, cursor, exec

I would like to execute several times the same query using every time one different column and print the column name.

In other words I would like to execute the following:

**1st query**

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Name],[C12],'C12' AS [Description]
FROM #MyTable
```

**2nd query**

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Name],[C13],'C13' AS [Description]
FROM #MyTable
```

**3rd query**

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Name],[C14],'C14' AS [Description]
FROM #MyTable
```

What I have done since now is the following code:

```
DECLARE @Member AS VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE Csr cursor for SELECT 'C12' UNION SELECT 'C13' UNION SELECT 'C14'
OPEN Csr
    FETCH NEXT FROM Csr INTO @Member
    WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)

    BEGIN
        exec('SELECT DISTINCT [Name],'+@Member+', ''+@Member+'' AS [Description]
                    FROM #MyTable
            ')
        FETCH NEXT FROM Csr INTO @Member
    END
CLOSE Csr
DEALLOCATE Csr
```

that is close to the desidered result but instead the `Description` column I get

> +@Member+

instead of the value that is assigned to the variable every iteration.

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for cursor, it can be easily accomplished with dynamic SQL:

```
declare @query nvarchar(400) = ''
select @query = @query + ' select name,''' + name + ''',' + name + ' from #MyTable'  from tempdb.sys.columns
where object_id = (
    select object_id from tempdb.sys.tables
    where name like '#MyTable%'
) and name <> 'name'

execute sp_executesql @query
```